# Custom class in an array loop wont work

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying use a class (`question`) that will be attached in each element of the array, the loop works fine. My problem is when I try to use the class in jQuery nothing happens, its as if its not there...

I am aware that Angular adds `ng-scope` and `ng-binding` classes, could this be preventing jQuery maybe?

When I inspect the DOM theres no errors and my class is there , it just wont work!

Here is my code: **HTML**

```
<p ng-repeat="n in ['Human or Lemar King?','Name of your tribe?','Can you Boogie?'] | filter:query" class="question"> {{n}}</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
  $(".question").on('click',function() {
     alert("Ohh hail King Julien!")
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set an event handler on elements that aren't in the DOM tree yet.

You can either go angular way and add `ng-click`:

```
<p ng-click="doSomething()" ng-repeat="n in ['Human or Lemar King?','Name of your tribe?','Can you Boogie?'] | filter:query" class="question"> {{n}}</p>
```

Or you can set a live event on `<body>` (or on a closer parent of the element that is present in the DOM):

```
$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '.question', function() {
     alert("Ohh hail King Julien!")
  });      
});
```

Comment: I see... but `$(function () {...});` says run the script when DOM is ready or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: When the DOM is ready, Angular starts doing its magic, which does routing and controller stuff. So your $()s are executed before Angular has substituted views! If you're in an Angular app, I highly recommend using `ng-click` for this!

Comment: ... for this particular task, ng-click wont work cause the task is jQuery UI specific

Comment: I see, that is what I meant with "If you're in an Angular app". If the logic has no ties in Angular, other options might feel more natural!

Comment: @stevuu there's always a way to use `ng-click`. You can create a function in the scope that will call jQuery UI method.

Comment: Definitely! That's why I said "might feel more natural". If you're only tying into Angular for a click event while every other part of the widget/control/application is handled in jQuery (scrolling, key events, et cetera), it might not be the most logical/natural place!

Comment: @stevuu oops sorry, it was for D'lo DeProjuicer ;) I just don't like the second idea with delegated 'on' events.

Comment: I didnt know about creating functions in the scope that can call jQuery methods.. I will look into that. Appreciate the insight guys.